# propiedad text de la clase textview de android

Tags: android, textview

tenga una duda, antes para recuperar o guardar texto en un textview se utilizaban los metodos getText y setText, ahora bien ,  ayer me puse a trabajar con un textview  y el metodo getText no me aparecia en el listado de metodos recomendados cuando ponia

```
objectoTextView.
```

pero he visto que hay una propiedad de los texview llamada "text", que pasando un valor hace de setText , ademas tambien hace de getText cuando la llamo sin pasarle un valor....

```
objectoTextView.text="Hola mundo"
var variable=objectoTextView.Text
```

mi pregunta es ¿ los metodos getText y setText de los textview han quedado obsoletos y substituidos por "text" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que `getText()` y `setText()` son propios de `java` y `.text` es para `kotlin`.

Te puedes dar cuenta de la diferencia por que en java el codigo seria algo asi

```
TextView objetoTextView;
objetoTextView.getText();
```

y en kotlin es

```
var objetoTextView; //la diferencia es el var
objetoTextView.text //esto funciona como set o get, depende como lo uses
```

`Kotlin` es un lenguaje que es soportado por android de manera oficial (al igual que `java` o `c++`).

Lo que creo te debio de haber pasado es que creaste un nuevo activity y la opcion aveces no es visible, pero si haces scroll hacia abajo cuando creas un nuevo activity, te da a elegir en que lenguaje la quieres. Si cuando creaste tu proyecto elegiste darle soporte a kotlin, los activities por default son creados en kotlin a menos que lo cambies.
[image: activity con java o kotlin]

Comment: gracias, esa es la duda que tenia, pero no estaba seguro si getText y set Text pertenecia a la propia API de Android.... , y por culpa que en android actualmente puede funcionar java y kotlin simultaneamente, no estaba seguro si la propiedad text , pertenecia a kotlin y getText y setText a java....